# Grouping of Excel Data

Tags: c#, excel, console-application, grouping

I have a linq query which reads data from an excel file.This is the query.

```
var query = from r in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            select new
            {
                empno = r.Field<double>(dataTable.Columns[2]),
                name = r.Field<string>(dataTable.Columns[3]),
                won = r.Field<double>(dataTable.Columns[4]),
                wonName = r.Field<string>(dataTable.Columns[5]),
                wo = r.Field<double>(dataTable.Columns[6]),
                billamount = r.Field<decimal>(dataTable.Columns[21])
            };
```

I want it to be grouped based on `wo(wo = r.Field<double>(dataTable.Columns[6]))`. I dont want to use queries to group. Is there any other ways to group data from excel sheet using c# code as console application.
Please help me out.
Thank you in advance

Comment: After grouping what exactly do you want to do with other properties like empno ?

Comment: billamount should be added to give a total bill amount for that particular wo. and other properties should be displayed along with it. i suppose u can understand what i am doing